# What are the moon phases in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, nature

Here is a list of phases that we distinguish in English (taken from [here](http://www.astro.wisc.edu/~dolan/java/MoonPhase.html)):

- Full Moon
- Waning Gibbous Moon
- Last Quarter Moon
- Waning Crescent Moon
- New Moon
- Waxing Crescent Moon
- First Quarter Moon
- Waxing Gibbous Moon

Does Latin distinguish the same phases of the moon? If so, I'd love a comprehensive list of words (and examples!) that Romans (or later astronomers) would use.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This question makes me recall my childhood. I see two approaches to an answer: 1. there is a complete list from a XVII century author, and 2. a compilation of classical and post-classical names by L&S.

### 1. Complete list (late Latin)

According to the [Harmonia Macrocosmica](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Cellarius_Harmonia_Macrocosmica) by [Andreas Cellarius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreas_Cellarius) (XVII century,) the phases are:

- New Moon: **Novilunium** *(Soli coniuncta)*,
- Crescent: **Cornicularis** *(in aspectu sextili)*,
- Quarter: **Dimidiata** *(in aspectu quadrato)*,
- Gibbous: **In orbem insinuata** *(in aspectu trino vel trigono)* and
- Full: **Plenilunium** *(Soli opposita)*

The intermediate ones, in turn, may be **crescens** ( waxing) and **decrescens** ( waning; remember Carmina Burana/O Fortuna?) He even goes to name the phase for every single day of the lunar cicle (larger image [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Typus_selenographicus_Lunae_phases_et_aspectus_varios_adumbrans_-_CBT_5870173.jpg).) Note that in English *crescent* refers to the shape (), while in Latin *crescens* means *growing* (i.e. waxing)

[image]

### 2. Older uses:

[Novilunium](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dnovilunium) and [plenilunium](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dplenilunium) are postclassical, and according to L&S, classical names were **luna nova** and **luna plena**.

[Luna](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=luna1&highlight=luna%2Ccrescens) entry in L&S lists **crescens** and **decrescens**, as well as instances of **dimidiata** (by Cato,) **extrema** and **prima** (by Varro) and specific days as counted from the last New Moon (e.g. **quinta decima luna**, [Columella, *Res Rustica*, 2, 10](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Col.%202.10&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2008.01.0504)),

Comment: This is exactly was I was looking for! ...though I'm a little disappointed that "gibbous" has such a clunky equivalent (*in orbem insinuata*).

Answer (score 6):

I should think that all of these have names in Latin. From my reading I recall only a passage in Pliny, Nat. 16.190, where he says that the time of conjunction (true new moon) has three names: coitus, dies interlunii and dies silentis lunae.

> inter omnes vero convenit utilissime in coitu eius sterni, quem diem
>   alii interlunii, alii silentis lunae appellant.